# Laravel не могу получить subject поле

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, bootstrap

В баззе данных у меня есть 3 поля email,subject,message
не могу получить subject

```
 **@foreach($rewiws as $element)
    <div class=" alert alert-primary text text-red">
    <h3>{{ $element->email}}</h3>
    <h3>{{ $element->subject}}</h3>
    <h3>{{ $element->message}}</h3>
    </div>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Какая ошибка то? В каком смысле не можете получить? Что выводится?

Comment: выдается пустая страка,если через инспект елемент посмотреть

Comment: в бд поле действительно не пустое? в классе модели в fillable не забыли добавить поле?